# How to save fragment's state across fragment transactions

Tags: android-fragments, android

I am having some difficulties in wrapping my head around android fragments. I have an `ActionBar` with a `Spinner` and I create a new `Fragment` on every click on the spinner item. I have something like the following code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
   ...  
   ...
   private void initActionBarSpinner()
   {
      getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

      OnNavigationListener callback = new OnNavigationListener()
      {
          @Override
          public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId)
          {
             if (itemPosition >= 0 && itemPosition < dataSet.size())
             {
                openTagFragment(itemPosition);
                return true;
             }

             return false;
          }
       };

       spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.action_bar_spinner, R.id.spinnertAdapterItem, tags);
       getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(spinnerAdapter, callback);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      Log.d(TAG, TAG + " oncreate");

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      initActionBarSpinnerAdapter();
   }

   protected void openTagFragment(int itemPosition)
   {
      Log.d(TAG, "Replacing fragment");

      String fragmentTag = dataSet.get(itemPosition);
      MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
      myFragment.setData(dataSet.get(itemPosition));
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFragment, fragmentTag);
      fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }
}
```

Problem I am facing: on orientation change, a new fragment gets created, which means it fetches the same data again from the server. I can see `onSaveInstanceState()` getting called on existing fragment when rotated but if I am going to do a new on `Fragment` again, when and how will I get a valid savedInstance bundle on fragment's `onCreate()`?

Comment: do not put "Android:" in title. You got tags for this